# Where to find ubuntu vagrant's home folder on windows?

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile, ubuntu-10.04, vagrant-windows, synced-folder

Does anyone know where I can find the home folder for vagrant on windows? I've tried typing `/home/vagrant` in windows file explorer but it still doesn't pop up.
I've also tried using vagrant's synced folders option by reconfiguring the vagrant file and that doesn't work either. Here is the code from the vagrantfile:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
config.vm.synced_folder "c:/Users/Vanessa", "/home/vagrant"
config.vm.box = "mrgcastle/ubuntu-lucid32"
config.vm.box_version = "1.0.0.0"
end
```

Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks for all your help in advance

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are asking but follow this steps if you find what you want:

1. ssh into vagrant from the folder which has your Vagrantfile. For me the path is C:\TaskMaster\sandbox and inside sandbox folder run `vagrant ssh`.
2. Once you are in run: `cd /home/` and do `ls`.
3. `cd vagrant`

[image]

Let me know if you have a different question.

Comment: Hi thanks for your suggestion, I have a windows 10 host machine and I am trying to access the root directory of ubuntu vagrant guest machine. I've tried vagrant synced folders it doesn't work.